# filtrar resultados jQuery.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo um `jQuery.getJSON` na url http://api.vagalume.com.br/search.php

E caso o JSON retornar:

```
{"type":"notfound"}
```

ou

```
{"type":"song_notfound","art":{"id":"3ade68b7ga05f0ea3","name":"William Bald\u00e9","url":"http:\/\/www.vagalume.com.br\/william-balde\/"}}
```

Não queria executar alguns códigos, tentei como:

```
 if (data.type != "notfound" || data.type != "song_notfound") {
                    // Letra da música
                    $("#letraescrita").html("");

                    $("#letraescrita").html('<h3>Paroles: </h3><a href=' + data.mus[0].url + ' target=_blank>clique aqui</a><Br>' + data.mus[0].text);

                    $("#traducao").html("");
                    $("#traducao").html('<h3>traduction: </h3><Br>' + data.mus[0].translate[0].text);
                }
```

Mas acho que algo esta errado em:

```
 if (data.type != "notfound" || data.type != "song_notfound") {
```

Ele estra entrando dentro do `if` e dando erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

no  `data.mus[0].text`

Comment: Use && no lugar de ||

Comment: Valeu Leandro....Vc saberia me dizer como em js faço uma verificação para saber se data.mus[0].translate[0].text existe? as vezes não vem essa tag no json e ai da erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro é por que alguns dos registros do JSON não têm o campo que você está tentando acessar.

Para evitar o erro basta verificar primeiro se o campo existe antes de tentar ler os dados:

```
if (data.mus != null && data.mus.length > 0 && data.mus[0] != null)
// agora é seguro usar data.mus[0] neste ponto
```

Comment: perfeito, era isso mesmo, mas preciso fazer essa 3 verificações? só if (data.mus[0] != null) não seria suficiente?

Comment: Acho que não dá pra simplificar não, tem que ser as três verificações mesmo. O problema é que assim, pra você pegar o primeiro elemento da lista, ela primeiro não pode ser nula (**data.mus != null**) , e depois disso a lista não pode estar vazia (**data.mus.length > 0**) por que senão vai dar erro de tentativa de acesso em índice fora dos limites do vertor. Agora a terceira verificação é pra se ocorrer o caso de o vetor existir && não ser vazio mas o elemento ser nulo (**data.mus[0] != null**) ainda daria o erro de tentar acessar uma property de objeto nulo.